# How can I show my instruments' coefficients in `ivreg2`?

Tags: stata, instrumental-variables

I have a model like this:

```
Y = endog + exog1 + exog2 + exog3 + entity + time
endog = exog1 + exog2 + entity + time
```

(where `entity` and `time` are for fixed effects.)

In Stata, I am running:

```
. ivreg2 Y exog3 (endog = exog1 exog2), vce(cluster ccode)
>
---------------------------------------...
             |               Robust
           Y | Coefficient  std. err.  ...
-------------+-------------------------...
       endog |   .1504787   .0284598   ...
       exog3 |  -.3204752   .0432307   ...
---------------------------------------...
```

However, I would also like to obtain the coefficient and the Robust std. err. for `exog1`, since it is also an important variable in the theory. Is `exog1,exog2` even being considered in the second stage regression? I have also tried using `ivreghdfe` instead of `ivreg2`, but the result is the same.

I have tried running:

```
. ivreg2 Y exog1 exog2 exog3 (endog = exog1 exog2), vce(cluster ccode)
> Warning - duplicate variables detected
Duplicates:         exog1 exog2
equation not identified; must have at least as many instruments
not in the regression as there are instrumented variables
```

Comment: I don't know Stata but the warning seems pretty clear: exog2 and exog3 are duplicate. Have you checked whether they are the same?

Comment: The option `first` (added right after the comma) would normally give you detailed first-stage results, including instrument coefficients. But in your case it seems `ivreg2` doesn't even run because of the duplication issue.

Comment: @PeterFlom oh sorry I mistyped. It should say duplicates: `exog1 exog2`

Comment: @Durden the code runs without errors if I only run `ivreg2 Y exog3 (endog = exog1 exog2), vce(cluster ccode)` (eliminating `exog1 exog2` in the second stage)

Comment: OK, but still, there seem to be duplicated variables.